# Auto-scroll in div with React

Tags: reactjs, autoscroll

Having a `div` with dynamic logs content (`props.logs`), How can I auto scroll to the bottom?

```
  <div className='rc_logsContent' ref={logsRef}>
    <Collapse isOpened={isOpened} >
       <p
         dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: formatNote(props.logs)}}
       />
    </Collapse>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you are passing the `ref` to the div element in which your component is rendered. I would suggest you use a dummy div at the end of your content and then scroll to that whenever your component is updated. Just check with this modified code.

```
<div className="rc_logsContent">
  <Collapse isOpened={isOpened}>
    <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: formatNote(props.logs) }} />
    <div ref={logsRef} />
  </Collapse>
</div>;
```

Attaching a sandbox with the same scroll functionality. You can check and modify based on your requirements.

[image: Edit scrollToBottomExample (forked)]